# How can I replace or remove HTML entities like "&nbsp;" using BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am processing HTML using Python and the BeautifulSoup 4 library and I can't find an obvious way to replace `&nbsp;` with a space.  Instead it seems to be converted to a Unicode non-breaking space character.

Am I missing something obvious?  What is the best way to replace &nbsp; with a normal space using BeautifulSoup?

Edit to add that I am using the latest version, BeautifulSoup 4, so the `convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES` option in Beautiful Soup 3 isn't available.

Comment: But, it *is* a non-breaking space...

Comment: Yes I realise &nbsp; is a non-breaking space.  So you are saying the right thing to do is get the HTML snippet I want, then run a Unicode search and replace?  I guess that does what I want, I just thought there was an equivalent to the old convertEntities option.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See [Entities](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#entities) in the documentation. BeautifulSoup 4 produces proper Unicode for all entities:

> An incoming HTML or XML entity is always converted into the corresponding Unicode character.

Yes, `&nbsp;` is turned into a non-breaking space character. If you really want those to be space characters instead, you'll have to do a unicode replace.

Answer (score 31):

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<div>a&nbsp;b</div>')
>>> soup.prettify(formatter=lambda s: s.replace(u'\xa0', ' '))
u'<html>\n <body>\n  <div>\n   a b\n  </div>\n </body>\n</html>'
```

Comment: This is an elegant approach, to do the search and replace using a <code>formatter</code>.  However, if I hadn't seen @Martijn Pieters answer it would be a bit mysterious, so I will mark his as the accepted answer since it has more explanation.

Answer (score 17):

You can simply replace the non-breaking space unicode with a normal space.

```
nonBreakSpace = u'\xa0'
soup = soup.replace(nonBreakSpace, ' ')
```

A benefit is that even though you are using BeautifulSoup, you do not need to.

Answer (score 8):

Admittedly this is not using BeautifulSoup, but a more straightforward solution today may be some combination of [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) and [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize), depending on your data and what you want to do exactly.

```
>>> from html import unescape
>>> s = unescape('An enthusiastic member of the&nbsp;community')# Using the import here
>>> print(s)
>>> 'An enthusiastic member of the\xa0community'
>>> import unicodedata
>>> s = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', s)
>>> print(s)
>>> 'An enthusiastic member of the community'
```

Answer (score 5):

I had issues with json that soup.prettify() did not fix, so it worked with [unicodedata.normalize()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize):

```
import unicodedata
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
dat = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'date'})
print(f"date prints fine:'{dat.text}'")
print(f"json:{json.dumps(dat.text)}")
mydate = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD",dat.text)
print(f"json after normalizing:'{json.dumps(mydate)}'")
```

```
date prints fine:'03 Nov 19 17:51'
json:"03\u00a0Nov\u00a019\u00a017:51"
json after normalizing:'"03 Nov 19 17:51"'
```