# Beautiful Soup table scraping only scrapes some of the time

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, edgar

I'm working to extract a specific table out of a couple documents, that holds the signatures of the directors, for a couple companies using BeautifulSoup4. My program finds a heading above the section that holds the tables, then counts two tables down from that spot to find the correct table (The documents being government documents means that the format holds true in almost all cases). Currently, this is how I'm doing it:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(theDocument)

try:
   tables = soup.find(text=re.compile("Pursuant to the requirements of Section 13")).findNext('table').findNext('table').strings
except AttributeError as e:
   #deal with error, output failed URL to file
```

With this code, I'm finding the tables for about 70% of my searches, but some just throw the error. For example, [this document](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/000110465907013496/a07-1583_110k.htm) is one of the ones that does not find the table (you can find the section in the document by doing a CTRL+F for the re.compile string), however [this document](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/000104746916010246/a2227279z10-k.htm) from the same company and what looks like the same HTML formatting yields positive results.

Any ideas?

EDIT: the &nbsp may be a problem, but there's another one as well. Shortening the search string to not include the &nbsp still yields a failure.

EDIT2: There seems to be an underlying error that occurs sometimes. I tried printing out the HTML the data variable and got the following:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;sec&#46;gov&#47;Archives&#47;edgar&#47;data&#47;1800&#47;000110465907013496&#47;a07&#45;1583&#95;110k&#46;htm" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;ee9a1645&#46;1466687980&#46;5cc0b4f
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any way around this problem, while still removing the &nbsp?

EDIT 2: The answer below did solve the issue that I was having, so I have marked it as answered. That said, there was another underlying problem of random newlines in the string, so I modified my regex to check for '\s+' between all the words instead of just spaces. **MAKE SURE TO CHECK THE HTML CODE FOR THIS ERROR IF YOU GET STUCK ON A PROBLEM LIKE THIS.**

Comment: Did you try using a different parser? Eg: `BeautifulSoup(theDocument, 'html.parser')`

Comment: @Jkdc From one of the answers, I've tried using lxml as a secondary parser. It caused more errors than it solved :) That being said, it MAY work to pick up the cases that the first attempt doesn't catch.

Comment: @Jkdc the problem has developed if you wish to take a crack at it.

Comment: You may have had your ip banned for too many requests, you have also used a user-agent as in Alexce's answer?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes I have separated his code from my program and am running it as a separate program. The commented line is the URL that is producing errors. I'm scraping 600 web pages, so I don't know if it's a ip ban.... they would have shit me down months ago if it was an ip ban :)

Comment: So the commented url gives you `Access Denied`?

Comment: Sometimes yes. The site itself (sec.gov) isn't exactly stable, so I get around that by not using requests, and by using urllib. Urllib returns an error flag which I catch and can loop until it doesn't happen. Sometimes I get a hit, sometimes I don't.

Comment: requests also gives you a `status_code` which you can check, I imagine it is a 403

Comment: This is true, however the problem of not finding the section still persists even if I get a request to the server

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `&nbsp;` between the `Section` and `13`:

```
<font size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Pursuant to the requirements of Section&nbsp;13 or 15(d) of the Securities Exchange Act of 1934, Abbott Laboratories has duly caused
this report to be signed on its behalf by the undersigned, thereunto duly authorized. </font>
```

I would use a [searching function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) and [replace the `&nbsp;` with a regular space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15138705/771848) when checking the `.text` property:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/000110465907013496/a07-1583_110k.htm"
url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/000104746916010246/a2227279z10-k.htm"
response = requests.get(url, headers={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
})

data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

text_to_search = "Pursuant to the requirements of Section 13"
p = soup.find(lambda elm: elm.name == "p" and elm.text and text_to_search in elm.text.replace(u'\xa0', ' '))
tables = p.findNext('table').findNext('table').strings
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the fix. It solved some of the errors but spawned a large number of new ones. I will definitely be trying to incorporate some of your ideas into my code, perhaps as a third chance system.

Would you mind explaining how the soup.find line works? I haven't seen some of those elements before.

Comment: @Retroflux well, looks like it solved this particular problem you've asked about, feel free to ask a separate question(s) if need further help with the code. The trick I use in the answer is basically a function which helps to do a certain operation (replace in this case) on a text before checking if there is a desired substring. `BeautifulSoup` is quite flexible in locating elements and provides all sorts of ways to do that. Hope that helps.

Comment: After a lot of testing, I noticed that it was failing on this test even if I only search up to the word "Section", which would not include the &nbsp character. Could there be another reason why this is failing?

Comment: Also, why do you use \xa0 in your replace and not &nbsp? I also found another error that spawned from the requests chunk of the code you provided. Are you aware of any workarounds for such an error?

Comment: Just ran your code separate from my program and it seems like p is set to None, even over multiple trials, for the document that I'm having trouble scraping.