# How to allow replacements with unsafe HTML in BS4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am converting some HTML cleanup code from JS to Python and BS4. The JS version uses nasty regex ways to clean up, and I've converted a bunch of them to much nicer, idiomatic BS4 code.

However, there's a chunk of the JS that works pretty well, and it uses a dictionary of patterns and replacements for a regex to work on.

I've converted the code to BS4, but I can't work out how to allow it to inject raw html back into the tree. I appreciate that this is the [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006463/beautiful-soup-4-how-to-replace-a-tag-with-text-and-another-tag) way to do this, but it's a lot of work for not much benefit. Is it the *only* way to achieve it?

## Example code

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_html = """
<H2>These paragraphs try to demonstrate the html upgrades.</H2>
<p>For example if my wood is 2x4 or is 5 x 9, 4 x8, then I should see &times;, not x.</p>
<p>Mdash with spaces to Mdash without &mdash;  smoosh!</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(my_html, "html.parser")

upgrades = [
    {
        "name": "x to times",
        "regex": r"(\d+\"*)\s*x\s*(\d+)",
        "replaceString": r'\1<span class="wp-times">&times;</span>\1',
    },
    {
        "name": "Mdash with spaces to Mdash without",
        "regex": r"\s*(&mdash;|—)\s*",
        "replaceString": r'<span class="wp-mdash"><wbr>&mdash;<wbr></span>',
    },
    # This list goes on and on... 
]

for upgradeSpec in upgrades:
    print(upgradeSpec, "matches:")
    p = re.compile(upgradeSpec["regex"])
    for text in soup.findAll(text=p):
        print("  ", text)
        new_string = p.sub(upgradeSpec["replaceString"], text)
        print("  ", new_string)
        text.replace_with(new_string)

print(soup)
```

### Which outputs:

```
<h2>These paragraphs try to demonstrate the html upgrades.</h2>
<p>For example if my wood is 2&lt;span class="wp-times"&gt;&amp;times;&lt;/span&gt;2 or is 5&lt;span class="wp-times"&gt;&amp;times;&lt;/span&gt;5, 4&lt;span class="wp-times"&gt;&amp;times;&lt;/span&gt;4, then I should see ×, not x.</p>
<p>Mdash (html) with spaces to Mdash without&lt;span class="wp-mdash"&gt;&lt;wbr&gt;&amp;mdash;&lt;wbr&gt;&lt;/span&gt;smoosh!</p>
```

### But I want:

```
<h2>These paragraphs try to demonstrate the html upgrades.</h2>
<p>For example if my wood is 2<span class="wp-times">&times;</span>2 or is 5<span class="wp-times">&times;</span>5, 4<span class="wp-times">&times;</span>4, then I should see ×, not x.</p>
<p>Mdash (html) with spaces to Mdash without<span class="wp-mdash"><wbr>&mdash;<wbr></span>smoosh!</p>
```

## Question:

If there's a way to allow my dirty regex ways, that'd be great. (Do I need to [define a formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138406/how-can-i-replace-or-remove-html-entities-like-nbsp-using-beautifulsoup-4)?)

If not, what's the best way to handle a multi-replacement string? (and I'll just cop all the extra work )

Answer (score 0):

*A possible* answer is to make the new string, then re-parse it into a bs4 tree, then replace the text being modified with that new tree:

```
for upgradeSpec in upgrades:
    print(upgradeSpec, "matches:")
    p = re.compile(upgradeSpec["regex"])
    for text in soup.findAll(text=p):
        print("  ", text)
        new_string = p.sub(upgradeSpec["replaceString"], text)
        print("  ", new_string)
        new_soup = BeautifulSoup(new_string, "html.parser")
        text.replace_with(new_soup)
```