# BeautifulSoup Find tag with text containing &nbsp;

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the `html` code and I want to find a tag by its text but because it has `&nbsp;` the result is `None`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<li><strong>Hello&nbsp;</li>', 'html.parser')
text1 = soup.find('strong', text = 'Hello')
text2 = soup.find('strong', text = 'Hello ')
text3 = soup.find('strong', text = 'Hello&nbsp;')
print(text1, text2, text3)
```

Output:

```
None None None
```

How can I handle `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I replace or remove HTML entities like "&nbsp;" using BeautifulSoup 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138406/how-can-i-replace-or-remove-html-entities-like-nbsp-using-beautifulsoup-4)

Comment: @SumnerEvans Not Work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-breaking space is parsed as `\xa0`, so you can either run:

```
text = soup.find('strong', text='Hello\xa0')
```

Or you could use regex:

```
import re
text = soup.find('strong', text=re.compile("Hello"))
```

Alternatively you could use a lambda function that looks for `Hello` at the start of the string:

```
text = soup.find("strong", text=lambda value: value.startswith("Hello"))
```